# Editable popover for ng-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ngtable

I am using angular js ng-table and want to show editable popover for the same.I am looking for updating my td records using that custom popover.

I have one custom directive for editable popover.Moreover it is working with simple table.But not working with ng-table.

JsFiddle for simple table popover : `"http://jsfiddle.net/9fcs3h8y/"`

For same code in ng-table I am getting following error on console:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="user ID" ng-model="user.city" type="text"> <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="user ID" ng-model="user.city" type="text">
```

Comment: You can use this directive [ng-tooltip](https://github.com/AbuMuslimAmr/ng-tooltip), It is a felxible Angular tooltip with a lot of handy options including html content.

Comment: I want form elements in that popover with two way data binding